# Handling images from XMLHttpRequest (with HTML and Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, xml, image, dom

I am using an XMLHttpRequest to fetch an image from a server (run locally from a third party server-applet)

A **simplified** version of the code is shown below.

The image is returned as a JPEG and the returned header shows "content-type= image/jpg".  I can view the information via Firebug for Firefox.

However I am having a terrible time being able to show the actual image on a webpage because it is the image data being returned from the server NOT a uri to the image location.

What is the proper way to display this image from the returned data?  Should I be using a `<span>` tag or an `<img>` tag or a `<magical-show-image-from-data>` tag?

```
function getXML(url, postData, requestStateChangeHandler){        
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {//Code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = requestStateChangeHandler;

    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    xmlhttp.send(postData);
}


function requestStateChangeHandler(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) 
    {
        if(xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        else
            dump("Error loading page\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Awww. You'll have to use a `data:` URI that will have all sorts of limitations in the IE family (won't work at all in IE <= 7, max size 32k in IE8). Is there really no way of getting an image URL instead?

Comment: If you are setting the proper headers for the image, and dumping the raw image data, just using the src attribute should work fine. The file extension is not important.

Comment: Setting the `src` attribute of `<image>` to your `url` works for dynamic contents too, but only with GET request, not with POST :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use inline images

on server side encode your response in base64

in php use `base64_encode("your data")`
and in javascript

```
result = document.getElementById('results');
result.innerHTML = '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,' + xmlhttp.responseText + '"/>';
```

Comment: Unfortunately this approach did not work because I could not tell the server to send base64 encoded responses.  (The server is a canned third party product)

Comment: Then convert it to base64 using javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-to-base64-using-javascript

Answer (score 3):

W3C is working on [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) and [XMLHttpRequest Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-XMLHttpRequest2-20100907/) to provide a unified experience with Blob for your requirement. You may want to investigate if any existing browser has implemented this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the easiest thing to do would be to set up a local proxy service that you can access via a GET and URL parameters, and on the back end it does the POST to the original image service, receives the image data back, and passes it back to you. Then you just put the URL of your proxy (with parameters) into the img src attribute.

```
<img src="http://myproxy/foo.jpg?param1=bar&param2=baz" />
```

The proxy at myproxy POSTs a request to the image servlet accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use Ajax?  Why not just add an image to your DOM?  When I type the following code in to my debugger in chromium it appends the PHP logo to the current page:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('img')).setAttribute('src', 'http://static.php.net/www.php.net/images/php.gif');
```

?

Comment: Yes AJAX is required, I need to dynamically request images from the server using XML queries to change request details

Comment: You can use this method dynamically too.  XHR is designed for text based content and it looks like the server is giving you back 'binary' content (`content-type= image/jpg`).   Looks to me like you're attacking a square hold with a round peg.

Comment: this works with `GET` request, won't work if the server is responding with image to only `POST`.