# How to render xmlhttpresponse as image

Tags: javascript

How can I render raw image content as image file ?

```
 function reqListener () {
      console.log(this.responseText);
    }

    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.onload = reqListener;
    oReq.open("POST", "http://static3.filehorse.com/icons-web/office-and-business-tools/zoho-icon-32.png", true);
    oReq.send();
```

I am getting raw file data like this

> �PNG
>
> IHDR 
>   szz�  lIDATxڭ�y�T������f�gz`�a�dDY�(F�RQˍ�/+��&����)�1Vi4��Q��!)4*jDL�DT��+��A�f�~������&
>   �h�r�n�{��;�w�9�|�
>   �O��տ�5����|��������_��N:&�)�]�".*���RȵK�.[�t����bK��c��9ÀQ���L`���B�xlݖy��u�X���i���ʱɱ�q(���'��̜�}_�7��  4   ����]=%��b���r�D$�,#+I���
>   ƚ��˗�]�4�Ȃ��?ݧ�'ϩ:g^�\�]Y^ܸ��KJw����q������
>   fi��̪���ډ�xI��hk��xk�����90~Wp!@HQ���`��+_c &O&)ch���
>   x�u5���Zߥ��CL�Ĥ+�3�7�����b6��S��~ URƭ@
>   ����(��0�)�.��*0�f�x
>   ��O%���#V������jD"�����|_0K�U�pң����M�J쀱D��h��&bV��1���~�1��'aaS��������������zV� ���׮��1U#�=r*M5���zK-�d��q�?�;b�n���r
>   r�H��.�e�:�M]�6!z�y�n-)���6<ϣ��Fʫ���/���s�<��<L[���䈎=ꀑ�C�8�0�k�t��^Z/[Ȧ����C
>   D�O$q��cN�6ez�p���*^ۺ���[BG��u�-\�z1����O�ޫE �:��?��
>   [B[����3XcP�<�_.ĭ�#��J��^�D�O���3�#��ᄱG�����H#&]2A��`�q�45��t;��~������.
>   Y �d-$5g�e��7���h[�Gl,���8I����:�Ci���� i�ߎ#�(-�������
>   Q���D1�����ɠ�(�q�#���N���rï(|ъ��(A�'hͰ�w�BT���wb�W�2��![��?�4*\�:7�6ԷQX��}j��EAT*1��K��Eǣ����(��/��AA���Z)�Ld(D��?!�s�GL�����q͡?`��Ϣ�\�s���>K���Vd]-u眎����q�\�'⤪�~���>�8���"��M^��g��<�q*�M���=�I�+�Z���U���U��O�W��i:�lE+*Ʀ9�ݕ_��]ƺ_N�շ(V��
>   �9��0�    �;�d����)Ǟ��)sdC"E��[��k�»�_�a�V��M���2��C�=��E���`kC�:z��֍7�-~i���+�|��#W�.;��/�+���ҍH�xv�h��_?��/����۔\��g���d4~�����
>   ��E��V���n<ƃ���i>/}4� �Y�u&#�h��Y��hR�p����ה|)���A��
>   ��{澽��3���k����W�cXCY;���6n���͓�z�k�l�g7�p��֭$l�A����m��e�I����4�D��CIi2~D�ҟ�˗��d5�T:qF��S�߾GDn�Z@�T^���n�`hM�����)x{[��b���1��X���#W"#Њ���-����8T�a���4�MX-���7
>   2�L�LLJ���{O�Rs����l�e���s�x��    ���nj=�3��q�ᣉ{h�Td���h� �ر��"�t
>   �_�g�6P   P����ڂ~���~ϕ9��%b5����Dh�@1���gdU���8�!D
>   _U�&���q��UPy6� ;���skuaC�U����{'�y��R�=��}>�$��_���f|�4V�!�  �Ƣ<+��Y��q��4l�e��GC�KD�%P9���ػ����&2^�U�J\1kw̝�S������S� 
>   �*����R1�Nl��`�ʍ�ߎ�./�$N)��^�pw��޶� ��r��x�xJ�&W�Lo���!��
>   ����@H;@i��#AO��i������w�xyC7��l�m�g������lf4�@X
>   �E�����:^V�@�3r��z�ʔC �s3F5#,ͽe���o�2P,��/j�F�\TE1�
>   �O!���^� ���
>   ֙#.(ά�j��C��Cc�����C͡��q�.*�h���M��$<�B���Rf{=�r��3�AL�=6u"�;u�B�۽��&��o�}˱ս�*D�zr%����䌡*����
>   �
>   (A��;�|����X��/�g�"'ބ�;�l,�b�=��r���j@�Oh��؞P�a._k�{�;�]@'�h���k?G�6\����l�W��p���º��&��=D�xpؠ
>   J�Y   ���E���:7��P[]CmA�M�D�d���{\��郌�����m#0a����q���*��pE˻����V��Ш��IEND�B`�

How can I render this content as image file ?

Comment: You cannot render images in the Javascript *console*

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721764/handling-images-from-xmlhttprequest-with-html-and-javascript

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = this.responseText;
document.body.appendChild(img);
```